# Regist form cannot be sent

Tags: python, html, django

Regist form cannot be sent.
I wrote in views.py

```
def login(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.save()
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
            'login_form': login_form,
            'regist_form': regist_form,
        }
        return redirect('profile')

    context = {
        'login_form': login_form,
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/login.html', context)
```

in login.html

```
<body>
    <ul class="top-menu">
                <h3 class="login">Login</h3>

                <div class="container">
                <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" role="form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="email_form">Email</label>
                    <input for="id_email" name="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="password_form">Password</label>
                    <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" value="" minlength="8" maxlength="12" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
                <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ next }}"/>
                </form>

                </div>
            </ul>

     <div class="newaccount">
          <h2>New Account registration</h2>
          <form class="form-inline" action="{% url 'accounts:detail' %}" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_username">Username</label>
                {{ form.username }}
                {{ form.username.errors }}
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_email">Email</label>
                {{ form.email }}
                {{ form.email.errors }}
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_password">Password</label>
                {{ form.password1 }}
                {{ form.password1.errors }}
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_password">Password(conformation）</label>
                  {{ form.password2 }}
                  {{ form.password2.errors }}
                  <p class="help-block">{{ form.password2.help_text }}</p>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Regist</button>
              <input name="next" type="hidden"/>
              {% csrf_token %}
            </form>
          </div>
</body>
```

in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import User

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['classF'] = 'form-control'
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login,name='login'),
]
```

No error happens in login form ,but in registration form  all input field is not shown.I think RegisterForm cannot be sent, but I really cannot understand why all input field  of LoginForm is ok although I send LoginForm by using same way of RegisterForm.
How should I fix this?What should I write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're render HTML with `login_form` and `register_form` in your form HTML.

But you're trying to render with `form` var instead of `register_form`, so django doesn't know what to render.

If you try to render not-exist variable in django template engine, it just show `Nothing` at all. So there will be NO errors!

Change your HTML code like this:

```
<body>
<ul class="top-menu">
    <h3 class="login">Login</h3>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" role="form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="email_form">Email</label>
                <input for="id_email" name="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="password_form">Password</label>
                <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" value="" minlength="8" maxlength="12"
                       placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ next }}"/>
        </form>

    </div>
</ul>

<div class="newaccount">
    <h2>New Account registration</h2>
    <form class="form-inline" action="{% url 'accounts:detail' %}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_username">Username</label>
            {{ regist_form.username }}
            {{ regist_form.username.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_email">Email</label>
            {{ regist_form.email }}
            {{ regist_form.email.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_password">Password</label>
            {{ regist_form.password1 }}
            {{ regist_form.password1.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_password">Password(conformation）</label>
            {{ regist_form.password2 }}
            {{ regist_form.password2.errors }}
            <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Regist</button>
        <input name="next" type="hidden"/>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

This code will show your `input` tags.

And one thing more... Why don't you use `login_form` in your HTML?